# Are there any ways to prevent 'com.htc.bg force close' issues?

Tags: force-close, htc-legend

I have a HTC Legend, and on occasion, I get an error "Process com.htc.bg has stopped unexpectedly".

According to other forums, this *could* be caused by issues with internet connectivity relating to updating Facebook contacts.

I have removed the syncing of Facebook all together (only syncs when I force it to), but I am still getting these errors.

Has anyone else worked out what is causing these issues, and how to resolve it? The processing crashing is usually just a popup, the process restarts ok without any issue, but on occasion the entire thing locks up, restarts, or the home screen reloads (as if coming from a restart)

Answer (score 3):

I have also experienced this problem with an Exchange account.  My solution was to remove the account completely and re-add it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a Legend, nor HTC, but some googling turned these out:

- http://androidforums.com/htc-droid-eris/59163-process-com-htc-bg-has-stopped-unexpectedly-please-try-again-wtf.html
- http://www.incredibleforum.com/forum/htc-incredible-help/224-error-message-com-htc-bg.html

apparently it's related to Facebook Sync.

Comment: I have found this as well. After the first few syncs and a few restarts, the issue has not occurred again.

Answer (score 1):

I had this while using "go launcher ex notifications" seems it was running two notifications at the same time, made a conflict, so I uninstalled and it seems fine. HTC desire.